# How do I get the file name and format from the string and save it with this name and format?

Tags: c#

```
wc.DownloadFile(src.Value, @"d:\MyImages\" + images.ToString("D6"));
```

`wc` is `WebClient`.

`src.Value` for example would contain `www.google.com\danny.jpg`. I want to save it on my hard disk as `danny.jpg`. And if in `src.Value` there is `www.google.com\moses.png` then on my hard disk it will be `moses.png`.

To save it as it is in `src.Value`, the name of the file with its format, png, jpg, gif or whatever format it is.

The variable images isn't in the `Form1` level which I move up each time I'm saving like:

```
images++;
```

So now each time it's saving a file from the link on my hard disk it will be 000000 then 000001 then 000002, etc. But I want to save them as they appear in the link with its name and format.

Comment: Is `src.Value` a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a simple example:

```
string str = "www.google.com/xyz/abc/danny.jpg";
string[] arr = str.Split('/');
string img = arr[arr.length-1];    
wc.DownloadFile(src.Value, @"d:\MyImages\" + img);
```

`img` will give you the filename you want to save on hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Uri.Segments`:

sample code:

```
String fileToDL = @"http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png";
Uri uri = new Uri(fileToDL );
var filename = uri.Segments.Last();
wc.DownloadFile(Path.Combine(@"d:\MyImages", filename), fileToDL);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is quite hard to understand what your problem is.
So I'll try to answer what I understood so far.

I guess you have some problem with saving the downloaded image with it's correct name.

In your example you have some kind of control or class called `src` with a property `Value`.
I assume that in this case `src.Value` will output e.g. "www.google.com\moses.png".
You just have to extract "moses.png" from this string and store it in a separate variable.

Regarding to what MSDN says about `WebClient` there should be no problem.

Please check [MSDN - WebClient.DownloadFile Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) for more information about this method and an example.

I hope I could help you but if not please describe your problem a bit better :)